# Time simulation program will not run

Tags: c++, simulation

I am making a simuaktion program and it closes automatically after parameters have been setup instead of beginning, any clues?

The program complies and runs fine, just doesn't do the actual simulation part...

```
void simulate(int timeHours, agent assignAgent[], campaign assignCamp[], int &numOfAgents)
{
    const int sim_time_min = timeHours * 60;

    if (system("CLS")) 
    {
        system("clear");    //clears window - this method is not recommeneded fix later using win32 api
    }

    cout << "***Simulation has begun***" << endl << endl;

    for(int minuteCounter = 0; minuteCounter <= sim_time_min; minuteCounter++)
    {
        tickNow(assignAgent, assignCamp, numOfAgents);

        //Sleep(1000);  //pause for one second
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to break it down a bit more: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Seems like a problem with `system("CLS")`and `system("clear")`. cls and clear **really bad things**. Avoid it use

Comment: For what it's worth, this would be much better modeled as a discrete-event model rather than a time-step model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set simulationTimeInHours to non-zero in your main function.

```
 for(int minuteCounter = 0; minuteCounter <= sim_time_min; minuteCounter++)
```

In your simulate function, simulationTimeInHours is sim_time_min above and as you can see minuteCounter is 0 and sim_time_min is 0 so the simulation never starts.